# Is SQLite3 calling any servers?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am totally new to Python and SQLite, and I was wondering if

```
conn3=sqlite3.connect("Test.db")
cur3=conn3.cursor()
conn3.commit()
```

calls any servers and nothing goes outside the machine.

Comment: See https://www.sqlite.org/serverless.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

SQLite creates a local database file from which it does its operations.  After you succesfully connect to such a database you should see that file appear in the same folder as where you executed it (or if you specified an explicit location, you'd see it there).